# While loop inside my switch statement to validate user input, but keep getting invalid input although it is valid.

Tags: java, validation, while-loop

So I'm creating a menu so the user can choose from a series of options, but I'm having trouble with getting the user to input a valid choice. I have tried using a while loop inside my case 1, but every time I type 1 or 2 which are valid inputs, my output is 'invalid input'. Here is part of my menu:

```
int choice;
    double amount;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {
        System.out.printf("\n********* MENU ************\n1. Check balance\n2. withdraw\n3. Deposit\n4. Change Annual Interest Rate\n5. Calculate Monthly Interest\n6. Display Account Info\n7. Exit\nEnter your choice: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        switch(choice) {
            case 1: System.out.printf("Check balance for saver1(1) or saver2(2)? ");
                    choice = input.nextInt();
                   while(choice != 1 || choice != 2) {
                    System.out.printf("Please enter a valid choice: ");
                     choice = input.nextInt();
                   }
                    if(choice != 1 || choice != 2) {
                        System.out.printf("Invalid input: ");
                        choice = input.nextInt();
                    }
                    if(choice == 1) {
                        System.out.println(saver1.getBalance());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(saver2.getBalance());
                    }
                    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition `choice != 1 || choice != 2` in your while loop and if statement to

```
choice != 1 && choice != 2
```

Because the problem is that if you enter `1`, then that won't equal `2`. So the original condition will evaluate to true since although the left side of the expression `choice != 1 || choice != 2` will evaluate to false, the right side will evaluate to true, making the entire expression evaluate to true. In this case, you'll never be able to leave the loop because you can't physically enter a number that is `1` **or** `2`

Answer (score 0):

If you type in 1 the choice will be equal to 1 but it will also be not equal to 2 which means that even if you type in 1 the if statement:

```
if(choice != 1 || choice != 2) {
                    System.out.printf("Invalid input: ");
                    choice = input.nextInt();
                }
```

will still execute because choice will not equal to 2.